# Hover over constant to see the value in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to hover over the constant to see the value in Eclipse.
Without having to click on the constant

Comment: What programming language? This sort of thing depends on the capabilities of the particular editor being used.

Comment: Do you want to know how to write a plugin that will do this, or are you asking if such a plugin already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for Java constants, with [Eclipse 4.29 (Q3 2023](https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.29/jdt.php#java-constant-hover):

> A new hover has been added to display the values of integer or float constants specified in binary, octal, or hex format.
>
> When hovering over such constants, the value will be shown in decimal format followed by the value in hex.
>
> The hover can be activated in the `Java > Editor > Hovers` preference page either by selecting the `Combined Hover` or by clicking on the `Java Constant` check box.
>
> [image: Java Constant Hover in preferences]
>
> The following shows hovering over an integer constant specified in octal format:
>
> [image: Example of Java Constant Hover]